# Open LinkedIn profile page from ios native app

Tags: ios, linkedin-api, deep-linking

I want to directly open LinkedIn app (already installed) from our app. I followed the LinkedIn deep link URL scheme like:

linkedin://profile?id=35932112

The LinkedIn app opens and shows the target person. However, when it is above 3rd degree connection, it shows very limited information and asks to upgrade to premium account. But if I navigates to other persons within LinkedIn app, I can still see the full profile even above 3rd degree connection.

Did I miss anything? Is it LinkedIn policy or I have to do some more configurations?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right, you cannot display information based on people that are not your primary connections. On newer versions of the app they restricted it even more; now it returns an error for second and third connections.

Answer (score 4):

Try using the profile's public url instead, it's working well for me.  The LinkedIn app will intercept it and open to the profile instead.  The url is usually right under the profile picture and has the following format:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/in/userid
```

Comment: Yes, this is great. Do you know why this works for Linkedin but not for Facebook?

Comment: This works, thank you. I want to add that if you want to display a profile of a company, the url would be https://www.linkedin.com/company/userId

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do that but it's not that straight forward. Not sure what your logic is like and will it be helpful but it's something.

So when you login with LinkedIn you can request the *public-profile-url* property, it will be returned in the result as *publicProfileUrl* and then you can save it in your backend. This way it will be saved for all the users that has authenticated for the app. When you try to open that link it will open the LinkedIn app or Safari with that profile.

PS: Hope this helps someone, I can see you question is some time ago :)